# Checking for ascending order on other columns when another column has duplicate values

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, rows

I have an Access Database that has only 1 table inside. That table consists of 2 fields. 
The `IG_Number` and the `TimeOfArrival`.

For example my fields have values for `IG_Number: 0,1,2,3,4` and for `TimeOfArrial: 12,15,19,5,19`. I have a code this SQL Command for ordering the `TimeOfArrival` field in ascending order:

```
SELECT * from myTable ORDER BY (TimeOfArrival);
```

Which gives me the results of the two tables

```
---------------------------
IG-NUMBER | TIMEOFARRIVAL |
---------------------------
3            5
0            12
4            19
1            19
---------------------------
```

But my question is, if there are duplicates in `TimeOfArrival` Table such as `19`. How can I have the ascending order of the `TimeOfArrival` according to the ascending order of those duplicates with the `IG-Number`?

So that, instead of having

```
-------------------------
4                 19
1                 19
-------------------------
```

I will have

```
----------------------
1                  19
4                  19
---------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `IG-NUMBER` to `order by`

```
Order by TimeOfArrival asc,IG-NUMBER asc
```

First result will be ordered by `TimeOfArrival` then on top of it result will be ordered again by `IG-NUMBER`

Comment: Well that was quick :) That solves it. Thank you so much.